# How to get nested if statement to work when checking for an initial value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wanting to check if column F's value ever equals "New Phase". If so then I want that cell's value to be "NA" and end the script. Otherwise, if the value does not equal "New Phase" for the second part of the if statement to run and populate the days function.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `,),` in the middle:

```
=IF(F3="New Phase","NA",DAYS(H3,TODAY()))
```

Comment: Good catch! Thanks that worked.